# Checking if outbound port 443 is blocked or not in a web server

Tags: php, web-services, server, telnet

I am trying to deploy a PHP application which involves oAuth with twitter on a free hosted web server, but the application is not working and resulting in an error like the following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Request error for API call: connect() timed out!' in 
/.../htdocs/src/codebird.php:1525 Stack trace: #0
/.../htdocs/src/codebird.php(1476): Codebird\Codebird->_callApiCurl('POST', 'oauth/request_t...', Array, false, false) #1 
/.../htdocs/src/codebird.php(508): Codebird\Codebird->_callApi('POST', 'oauth/request_t...', Array, false, false) #2 
/.../htdocs/index.php(13): Codebird\Codebird->__call('oauth_requestTo...', Array) #3 
/.../htdocs/index.php(13): Codebird\Codebird->oauth_requestToken(Array) #4 {main} thrown in /.../htdocs/src/codebird.php on line 1525
```

The owner of the library i have used for the application suggests to check if any firewall on the web server is blocking the outbound port 443. Being a newbie on networking, my question is how do i figure out if the  server is indeed blocking outbound port 443 connections. I tried to telnet from a windows machine on the domain name and port 443 and it shows blank screen which i read that suggests the port is open. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062908/how-can-i-test-an-outbound-connection-to-an-ip-address-as-well-as-a-specific-por

Answer (score 0):

Please check following links. This explains how you can check your server port blocked or not. If you have root access to your web server, you can check it with wget, telnet or nmap

- [How to easily determine, which outbound ports aren't blocked by firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/631087/how-to-easily-determine-which-outbound-ports-arent-blocked-by-firewall)
- [How can I test an outbound connection to an IP address as well as a specific port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062908/how-can-i-test-an-outbound-connection-to-an-ip-address-as-well-as-a-specific-por)
- [http://positon.org/an-outgoing-port-tester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062908/how-can-i-test-an-outbound-connection-to-an-ip-address-as-well-as-a-specific-por)

If you have command line access to the server and if links2 browser installed, you can visit to http://portquiz.net:443/ from the terminal.

**Install links2**

$ sudo apt-get install links2

**Check if port 443 is open from terminal browser**

$ links2 http://portquiz.net:443/

Comment: i dont think i have root/command line access to the server, cause its a freehosted one and i dont see any such options on the cpanel.