# Github Error "ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Tags: git, github, ssh

I had this error occur to me while trying to do a git push (previously I've had no issues connecting to remote):

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

I realized this was caused by the internet connection, as when I switched the wi-fi I no longer had this error and was again able to connect to github.

My question is: **Does anybody know why this error occurs, and is there a way to avoid this?**

This happens with my university wi-fi and it would be a shame if I cannot use github there.

Comment: "Resource temporarily unavailable" usually corresponds to an overloaded machine (EAGAIN error => out of memory / swap space), but this does depend on a lot of other things. When you get this sort of error it may be worth running with GIT_TRACE=1 or system tracing (`strace` on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.
What fixed it for me was running `ssh -T git@github.com` in my bash terminal.

Which should return:

> Hi {GitHubUserName}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
> provide shell access.

I did git push after this and it went through.

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558649/github-error-ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-operation-timed-out-fat) threads suggest it might be a firewall issue