# Git pull always fails on first try but succeeds on second

Tags: git, ssh

When I try to pull, push, or generally do anything to interact with my remote git repo over ssh, the command always fails immediately on the first try but then succeeds if I run it right after for a second time.

The error I get is:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Software caused connection abort
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Once I've run the second (successful) command it seems to reset it and it becomes fine for a period of time, but then if I come back after a couple hours or so, the same occurs. I've tried some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558649/github-error-ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-operation-timed-out-fat) but with no luck. Can anyone hazard any guesses as to where I can look to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a firewall that has port 22 closed but opens it on the 1st access; after some timeout it closes it again. The problem is not related to Git or SSH at all. Try to ask at Super User.

Comment: @phd thanks for input. I did try accessing it over port 443 as in the post I linked, but seems 443 has the same symptom. It might be blocking a bunch, I'll head that direction thank you.

Comment: "*…seems 443 has the same symptom.*" The same firewall, the same symptom. "*It might be blocking a bunch…*" Everything, most probably.